# Css issue - styled-components ( inside next.js app )

Tags: css, next.js, styled-components

Can someone explain to me why my `outline` is not working :/ ?

```
width: 92%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 2rem;

overflow: hidden;

input{

    width: 100%;

    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 200;

    border: 1.3px solid rgba(200, 200, 200);
    border-radius: .45rem;

    padding: 1.5rem 1rem;

   &:focus{
    outline: 1.4px solid #1877f2;
 }    

}
```

Results

[image]

If i let the default it works, but when i put its styles to none, it doesn't work, i check google dev stools and my code seems fine, but it still doesn't work :/

If i put background red inside the focus, it works, but outline doesn't

Help me :/

Comment: We could, if you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ... Also you perhaps can try `&:focus{ outline: none; border: 1.4px solid #1877f2; }`

Comment: That is not CSS, please add the proper tags (less/sass)